# What is the most efficient way to join one list to another in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, collections

I start with a list of integers from 1 to 1000 in `listOfRandoms`.

I would like to left join on `random` from the `createDatabase` list.

I am currently using a `find{}` statement within a loop to do this but feel like this is too heavy. Is there not a better (quicker) way to achieve same result?

#### Psuedo Code

```kotlin
data class DatabaseRow(
  val refKey: Int,
  val random: Int  
)

fun main() {
    val createDatabase = (1..1000).map { i -> DatabaseRow(i, Random()) }
    
    val listOfRandoms = (1..1000).map { j ->
        val lookup = createDatabase.find { it.refKey == j }
        lookup.random
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `ref_lookup`?  (Also, why are you using underscores?)  It looks like all you really want is `createDatabase[j]`.

Comment: ref_lookup is a typo, I have corrected. Regarding your second point, in my actual example, my `createDatabase` is a data class with 3 vars. You have me thinking now that I should convert it into a map with the 'lookup' index as the key and variable I need as the value. This seems like a much simpler and idiomatic way to 'join' the data. Do you know if using map[key] like this is faster than using the `find{}` statement?

Comment: Yes, for bigger data it is much faster to use a map here. `find{}` is `O(N)` for each item to find. Map is `O(N)` once to create it and then each access is `O(1)`.

Comment: You seem to be mixing up database and programming ideas, which makes the question hard to follow. (Also, your code doesn't compile, which doesn't help.) Do you only want a list of random numbers out of this? It so, then that can be done in far simpler ways. Otherwise, could you explain your real goal here?

Comment: I was not actually suggesting using a map, since your code makes it look like all you need is an array.  I suppose technically it'd be `createDatabase[i-1]`.  For the general case, a map would be appropriate, and yes, it would be faster.

Comment: @gidds As background, I was previously using an SQL left join statement to merge one dataset onto another using a common key (which I have simulated with `refKey` here). The actual data is not a random number but more sensical. I am now trying to achieve this natively with Kotlin. I have found this SQL to Kotlin migration to be a common theme I encounter.

Comment: @LouisWasserman in my real code, the key is not an ascending list starting from 0 but instead an ascending list starting from a random number, like 18123..19123. This is because my `key` is actually a `LocalDate` that I converted to `Long`. For this reason I have suggested using a map, as I believe arrays needs to have an index starting at 0. Please let me know if you see otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the question seems to be mixing up database and programming ideas, which isn't helping.

And it's not entirely clear which parts of the code are needed, and which can be replaced. I'm assuming that you already have the `createDatabase` list, but that `listOfRandoms` is open to improvement.

The ‘pseudo’ code compiles fine except that:

- You don't give an `import` for `Random()`, but none of the likely ones return an `Int`. I'm going to assume that should be `kotlin.random.Random.nextInt()`.
- And because `lookup` is nullable, you can't simply call `lookup.random`; a quick fix is `lookup!!.random`, but it would be safer to handle the null case properly with e.g. `lookup?.random ?: -1`. (That's irrelevant, though, given the assumption above.)

---

I think **the general solution is to create a [`Map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/)**. This can be done very easily from `createDatabase`, by calling [`associate()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/associate.html):

```
val map = createDatabase.associate{ it.refKey to it.random }
```

That should take time roughly proportional to the size of the list. Looking up values in the map is then very efficient (approx. constant time):

```
map[someKey]
```

---

In this case, that takes rather more memory than needed, because both keys and values are integers and will be boxed (stored as separate objects on the heap). Also, most maps use a hash table, which takes some memory.

Since the key is (according to comments) “an ascending list starting from a random number, like 18123..19123”, **in this particular case it can instead be stored in an `IntArray` without any boxing**. As you say, array indexes start from 0, so using the key directly would need a huge array and use only the last few cells — but if you know the start key, you could simply subtract that from the array index each time.

Creating such an array would be a bit more complex, for example:

```
val minKey = createDatabase.minOf{ it.refKey }
val maxKey = createDatabase.maxOf{ it.refKey }
val array = IntArray(maxKey - minKey + 1)
for (row in createDatabase)
    array[row.refKey - minKey] = row.random
```

You'd then access values with:

```
array[someKey - minKey]
```

…which is also constant-time.

Some caveats with this approach:

- If `createDatabase` is empty, then `minOf()` will throw a NoSuchElementException.
- If it has ‘holes’, omitting some keys inside that range, then the array will hold its default value of 0 — you can change that by using the alternative `IntArray` constructor which also takes a lambda giving the initial value.)
- Trying to look up a value outside that range will give an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Whether it's worth the extra complexity to save a bit of memory will depend on things like the size of the ‘database’, and how long it's in memory for; I wouldn't add that complexity unless you have good reason to think memory usage will be an issue.

Comment: Thanks. I imagine running this query over a dozen or more coroutines, with each 'database' being couple of thousand rows. Would the `minOf` and `maxOf` operations be expensive in terms of time to run i.e. is it ~'constant-time' or extrapolates with database size?

Comment: min/max have to scan through the entire list, so are linear (i.e. taking time proportional to the size of the list). (But then _anything_ you do with the list is likely to have at least that complexity.)